# How to find supported Direct3D Feature Levels

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to find which Direct 3D Feature Levels ([shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcommon/ne-d3dcommon-d3d_feature_level)) are supported in my C# UWP program.

Note: I am doing this in trying to research possible answers to my question [How do I know, in code, if RadialGradientBrush is not being shown correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520435/how-do-i-know-in-code-if-radialgradientbrush-is-not-being-shown-correctly)

In C++, there is a call to [D3D11CreateDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-d3d11createdevice) that might possibly be useful, but there does not appear to be a C# equivalent.

Or, even better, might be the [ID3D11Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11device), which has a [GetFeatureLevel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-getfeaturelevel) call. Again, these are C++ items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out:

C++ DLL:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <wrl.h>
#include <d3d11_2.h> 
#include "BKGraphicsDLL.h"

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL GetGraphicsFeatureLevel()
    {
        HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL MaxSupportedFeatureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1;
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevels[] = {
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
        };

        hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
            NULL,
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
            NULL,
            0,
            FeatureLevels,
            ARRAYSIZE(FeatureLevels),
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            NULL,
            &MaxSupportedFeatureLevel,
            NULL
        );

        return MaxSupportedFeatureLevel;
    }
}
```

An enum and a NativeMethods class to access the DLL in my MainPage C#:

```
    public enum D3DFeatureLevel
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1 = 0x9100,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2 = 0x9200,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3 = 0x9300,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0 = 0xa000,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1 = 0xa100,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 = 0xb000,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1 = 0xb100,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0 = 0xc000,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1 = 0xc100
    };


    // used to get Graphics capabilities
    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("BKGraphicsDLL.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern D3DFeatureLevel GetGraphicsFeatureLevel();

    }
```

Wherever I need to Feature Level in my code, uses this line:

```
    D3DFeatureLevel maxFeatureLevel = NativeMethods.GetGraphicsFeatureLevel();
```